# Retrieving Values From checkbox and editfield from the same horizontal field manager in blackberry

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

i have checkbox and editfield in two vertical field manager on the same horizontal field manager and its generating continuosly using for loop now how to take values from both correspondance field.